# how to pivot the Analysis variable in a cross table in SAS Visual Analytics (SAS/VA)

Tags: sas, pivot-table, sas-visual-analytics

## My problem

I should display a LASR-table in SAS/VA. For each row of the LASR-table, the report should have one column, with the class variable and a dozen of analysis variables. I am not supposed to do any data preparation (i.e. not use Data Builder).

How can I get all analysis variables underneath each other?

## Example

In base SAS `proc tabulate`, I can choose if my analysis variabel are side by side or above each other:

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.iris;
    class Species;
    var PetalWidth SepalWidth PetalLength SepalLength;
    table Species * (PetalWidth SepalWidth PetalLength SepalLength); /* side by side */
    table (PetalWidth SepalWidth PetalLength SepalLength), Species;  /* above each other */
run;
```

gives the below reults
[image]

In enterprise guide, I can do the same
[image]

In SAS/VA, I always get my analysis variable side by side. Can I change that?